# Display the first and last colors from the following list.%s

Tags: python

```
color_list = ["Red","Green","White" ,"Black"]
print( "%s %s"%(color_list[0],color_list[-1]))
```

Why add `"%s %s"%`,why not just `print(color_list [0],color_list[-1])`?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: That's it. You have already done it. What else are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry,I edit the question just now.

Comment: `print(color_list [0],color_list[-1])` also works. What is your question?

Comment: The meaning of "%s %s"%,Why we need add this

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `print(variable1,variable2)` and `print("%s %s"%(variable1,variable2))` is about the principle. What you're doing is actively inserting variables into a string that you define vs simply relying on the way that `print()` formats strings with variables. You could insert any number of variables into that string with very little formatting using the format string tools, and you could quickly and easily modify the output of the string to be more verbose more easily. For example:

```
print("The first color in the list is %s and the last color is %s." % (color_list[0],color_list[-1]))
```

It depends on your needs but one practices elements of string formatting and the other doesn't. String formatting is a powerful tool that allows for robust structuring of information into strings without complicated concatenations. If you're interested in learning more about string formatting you can read a more robust tutorial here:

https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/